# I am trying to connect a Spring Boot file with S3, but I am getting an error. The file is currently being deployed to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, heroku

The logic is that the server creates a pre-signed URL and returns it to the client when it receives a file name from the client.

I set IAM credentials & Region in IntelliJ local environment, and it worked well.

---

### Error

2023-07-28T02:45:07.611649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/products/upload" host=wili-be-ae9b2e96541b.herokuapp.com request_id=0cb317fb-f760-480f-9a9f-f4545799f719 fwd="119.207.186.233" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1035ms status=500 bytes=587 protocol=https
2023-07-28T02:45:07.609617+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.609  WARN 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] i.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher : Fail to retrieve token
2023-07-28T02:45:07.609643+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-28T02:45:07.609643+00:00 app[web.1]: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:

2023-07-28T02:45:07.609704+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

2023-07-28T02:45:07.609711+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.609 DEBUG 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] c.a.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain     : Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@6f0b0a5e: Failed to connect to service endpoint:
2023-07-28T02:45:07.609924+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.609 DEBUG 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] c.a.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain     : Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@4c398c80: profile file cannot be null
2023-07-28T02:45:07.610769+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.610 DEBUG 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
2023-07-28T02:45:07.610850+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.610 DEBUG 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Nothing to write: null body
2023-07-28T02:45:07.611118+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-07-28 02:45:07.611 DEBUG 2 --- [io-58824-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

### S3 code

#### S3Config

```
@Configuration
public class S3Config {
    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;
    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
        );
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
}
```

#### S3Controller

```
@RestController
public class S3Controller {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.bucket}")
    private String bucketName;

    @PostMapping("/products/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> getPresignedUrl(@RequestBody FileDto fileDto) {
        String decodedFileName;
        String fileName = fileDto.getFileName();
        try {
            decodedFileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }
        try {
            Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000);
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, decodedFileName)
                    .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                    .withExpiration(expiration);
            URL url = amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

            Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            resultMap.put("presignedURL", url.toString());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(resultMap);
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // AWS SDK에서 발생하는 에러 처리
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Heroku ConfigVars

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = MyAccessKey
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = MySecretKey
S3_BUCKET = MyS3Bucket
AWS_ROLE_ARN = MyAWSArn
AWS_PROFILE = MyAWSProfile
```

Comment: Can you try removing environment variables AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_PROFILE since you are loading access key ID and secret in your code? It should be sufficient to configure AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and S3_BUCKET  in Heroku config.

Comment: The same error persists even after removing AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_PROFILE from enviorment variables.

Comment: I think your properties in @Value fields should be `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretKey`. This will be equivalent to environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Please see this [Spring doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.3.RELEASE/multi/multi__basic_setup.html). Did you read credentials from environment variables in your local IDE?

Comment: I'm connecting to application.yml through @value and then to heroku. {aws.accessKeyId} Are you saying that I have to write the code like this?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: You might also need to read credentials using `new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()` in your Amazon S3 client config when reading from environment variables. I would suggest configuring these environment variables in your local machine, read credentials when running the app in IDE and test it.

Comment: The execution is not possible due to the reason that 'EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()' has private access in 'software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider'. To provide a better understanding, I'll share the GitHub repository address.

Comment: https://github.com/GGDomins/WiLi_BE

Comment: S3config is located inside the config directory.

Comment: I see that you have changed property keys in the project. Is it still not possible to read credentials from environment variables in Heroku?

Comment: Unfortunately.. yes